# Как уменьшить шрифт текста в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как уменьшить шрифт текста в канвас, чтобы он не выходил за пределы полотна? 
используя `measureText` и цикл `while`, в котором уменьшается шрифт, пока он шире `canvas`, шрифт уходит в минусы и ширина текста определяется неправильно.
как исправить?

```
var forFont = 30;
var topMeasure = context.measureText(top).width;
console.log(topMeasure);
while(topMeasure > canvas.width){
  forFont--;
}
context.font = forFont + "pt Impact";
```

Answer (score 1):

Да очень простое решение.

- Ширину канваса удобнее брать в константу.
- Далее размер шрифта берем на 1 больше, т.к чтобы меньше кода писать, проще реализовать через `do {} while();`

И вот что у нас получилось.

```
var CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width;

var txt = 'lorem impsum dolor ...';
var fontSize = 31;

do {
   fontSize--;
   ctx.font = fontSize + 'px Arial';
} while (ctx.measureText(txt).width > CANVAS_WIDTH);
```